# Is dependency injection useful in the domain model when applying Domain driven design?

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

DDD Newbie question:

I read in a blog somewhere that in a scenario where objects are closely associated with each other in a domain driven design, and where one object based on some complicated business rule is responsible for the creation of a dependent object, in such a design the usefulness of dependency injection is very limited.

Would you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I wouldn't agree.

The whole purpose of DDD is to arrive at an **expressive model** that **facilitates change**. It is accepted as a given that **business logic often changes**, so the model must be **flexible** enough to enable a quick change of direction in the face of changing requirements or new insight.

As Uncle Bob writes in [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), the only way to enable a flexible and expressive API that can quickly address unprecedented change is to use **loose coupling**. Loose coupling is achieved through the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle); from there, the connection to DI follows naturally.

As I read [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), this was always the underlying motivation behind all the talk about **Factories**, but I personally find the book a little vague there.